# Is it correct application of the SRP(single responsibility principle)?

Tags: java, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle, clean-architecture

I have a java class:

```
class User {
 private String name;
 private String address;
 private int age;
 private BigDecimal salary;
 // other fields
 //getters setters
}
```

I can receive a map of new values in these fields and update it. It looks like this: `ChangeItem changeItem` where **changeItem.key is field's name** and **changeItem.value is the field's value**

I create strategies for updating each field. For example common interface:

```
public interface UpdateStrategy<T> {
    T updateField(T t, ChangeItem changeItem) throws ValidationExceptions;
}
```

And some implementation:

```
public class UpdateNameStrategy implements UpdateStrategy<User> {

    private static final Pattern USER_NAME = Pattern.compile(...);

    @Override
    public User updateField(User user, ChangeItem changeItem) throws ValidationExceptions {

        String fieldValue = changeItem.value;

        if (!validate(fieldValue))
            throw new ValidationExceptions(changeItem);

        user.setName(fieldValue);

        return user;
    }

    private boolean validate(String value){
        return USER_NAME.matcher(value).matches();
     }
}
```

In the real project I have 40 fields and 40 strategies for each field(with different validation and logic).

I think this class violates the SRP(single responsibility principle). And I move validation logic to separately class. I change the validation method to:

```
public class UpdateNameStrategy implements UpdateStrategy<User> {

    @Override
    public User updateField(User user, ChangeItem changeItem) throws ValidationExceptions {

        String fieldValue = changeItem.value;

        ValidateFieldStrategy fieldValidator = new UserNameValidate(fieldValue);

        if (!fieldValidator.validate())
            throw new ValidationExceptions(changeItem);

        return user;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UserNameValidate implements ValidateFieldStrategy {

    private static final Pattern USER_NAME = Pattern.compile(...);

    private String value;

    public UserNameValidate(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate() {
        return USER_NAME.matcher(value).matches();
    }
}
```

And now I have 40 strategies for update fields and 40 validators. Is it the correct way? Or maybe I can change this code more clear?

Comment: What's the point of having a generic `UpdateNameStrategy` if you pass in a `User` and directly instantiate a `UserNameValidate`? The whole point of generics is to not have to write multiple implementations of underlying generic functionality. In any case, if this is anything other than a design exercise, it's *way* over-complicated, and I'd consider DI/IoC instead, especially since so far there doesn't seem to be a point to the use of generics.

Comment: @ Dave Newton I need to implement this functional for 2 types of classes. in real project `Payment` and `Charge`.

Comment: @Dave Newton I have a factory of strategies. `UpdateStrategy<User> 
updateStrategy = userUpdateStrategyResolver.getStrategyByFieldName(changeItem.fieldName)` and call `updateStrategy.updateFueld(User userFromDb, ChangeItem)`

Comment: to make use of generics in your case you either create abstract class AbstractUpdateNameStrategy with 2 abstract method for validation and update. Or if you do not want use inheritance, you can just pass 2 interfaces (IValidate, IUpdate) to the concrete UpdateNameStrategy class via constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry for  being blunt, my eyes are bleeding while looking at this. You took one unnecessarily complicated validation model and you split it in two to make it even more complicated. And none of it has much to do with the Single Responsibility Principle.

Without knowing anything specific to your domain problem, this looks like a superfluous usage of the Strategy pattern.

I've never seen a legitimate domain problem requiring a validation strategy split like this, for every single field.

An object in a domain is not just a collection of fields. It is also behavior governing the fields (which is the object state) and the rules governing the mutability of that state.

In general we want rich objects with behavior. And that behavior typically includes validation.

I sincerely doubt that every single field in a model requires validation to this level of granularity. Put the validation in the object's setter methods and be done with it.

You are killing  yourself doing all this elaborate setup. We all want structure, but at some point all of this is just ceremony for building very tall sand castles.

Validation in general is part of an object. And an object is responsible, it is its responsibility to govern its state, the collection of fields and values it possesses and controls.

Single Responsibility Principle does not mean extracting the responsibility of validating fields out of an object. That responsibility is intrinsic to the object.

Single Responsibility Principle concerns itself with "external" responsibility, the responsibility of an object to provide a single coherent function (or set of coherent functions) to someone that uses that object.

Consider a Printer object. This object is responsible to print. It is not responsible to manage the network connections between a printer and a user, for instance.

SRP is not limited to classes, but also packages and modules. A Mathematics module should provide you with, obviously, mathematical routines. It should not provide routines for filesystem manipulation, right?

That's what the SRP is about. What you are doing, extracting validation behavior out of an object, that has little, if anything, to do with SRP.

Sometimes one might want to extract out common validation routines (check if a string is black or null, or whether a number is a natural number.)

So you might have a class like this:

```
public class User {
    // some fields, blah blah

    public void setName(final String aName){
        if( aName == null || a.aName.trim().length() < 1){
            throw new SomeException("empty string blah blah");
        }
        this.name=aName.trim(); // model requires this to be trimmed.
    }

    public void setRawField(final String aValue){
        if( aName == null || a.aName.trim().length() < 1){
            throw new SomeException("empty string blah blah");
        }
        this.rawField=aValue;  // model requires this to not be trimmed.
    }

public void setRawField2(final String aValue){
    // model requires this field to be non-null,
    // can be blank, and if not blank, must be all lower case.
    if(aValue == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("null string blah blah");
    }
    this.rawField2=aValue.toLowerCase();

}
```

changed into a class that delegates minutia to an external validation utility class or module.

```
public class User {
     // some fields, blah blah

     public void setName(final String aName){
         // model requires this to be trimmed
         this.name=Validator.notEmptyOrDie(aName).trim();
     }

     public void setRawField(final String  aValue){
         // model requires this to *not* be trimmed
         this.rawField=Validator.notEmptyOrDie(aValue);
     }

public void setRawField2(final String aValue){
    // model requires this field to be non-null,
    // can be blank, and if not blank, must be all lower case.
    // too contrive to refactor, leave it here.
    if(aValue == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("null string blah blah");
    }
    this.rawField2=aValue.toLowerCase();

}

 public class Validator {
     static public String notEmptyOrDie(final String aString){
         if( aString == null || aString.trim().length() < 1){
             throw new SomeException("empty string blah blah");
         }
         return aString;
 }
```

This is an approach I actually follow, to refactor *parts* of common validation. I  factor out minutia.

But the core validation logic, if any, it remains **in the object.** Notice that validation is still part of the User class. All that got extracted is the minutia.

The logic that declares the intent of validation (*check if black or die*) still remains part of the User class. It is intrinsic to the class' behavior.

In  some models, the User class might not require validation at all. It might be just a data shuttle, a POJO.

OTH, in a model that requires it to validate its state, that state should usually go inside the class, and a developer must have a very good argument for extricating that logic the way you did in your sample code.

SRP says nothing about how you compose responsibility internal to the object, only external to consumers of said object.

As  a rule of thumb, validation of object fields belong to the object as logic internal to the object. It is intrinsic to the object's behavior, invariants, pre conditions and post conditions.

Very rarely you extract out the entire validation out of an object (unless we are talking  about POJOs serialized and deserialized by an external package, and with validations added declaratively via annotations or some sort of controlling configuration descriptor.)

Hit me up if you still have any questions. Not sure how fast I can answer back, but I don't mind to answer questions if I can.

**** EDIT ***

User @qujck mentions the valid concern in this proposed approach, that it is not possible to differentiate all validation exceptions (becuase they use common exceptions for all.)

One possibility (which I've used) is to have overloaded and/or polymorphic validators:

```
public class Validator {
    static public String notEmptyOrDie(final String aString){
        return Validator.notEmptyOrDie(aString, null);
    }

    static public String notEmptyOrDie(final String aString, 
                                       final String aFieldName){
        if( aString == null || aString.trim().length() < 1){
            throw new SomeException( 
                (aFieldName==null? "" : aFieldName + " ") 
                + "empty string blah blah");
        }
        return aString;
    }
}
```

If one uses a hierarchy of validation exceptions with common constructors, then one could take this further by passing the desired exception class, and use reflection to create instances to be thrown.

I've done that also. Actually, I'm doing that now for a common error-throwing mechanism in an EJB layer that itself reaches to another system via network protocols.

But that's something I do to cope with an existing system, not something I would do if I had a design choice. And it still limits itself to refactoring validation or error handling to its core elements.

Actual, object-specific validation still remains *at/within* the object itself.

Comment: I really like the question and this answer - the downside though here is you will get one exception for the first problem item of data - it's not possible to capture all the validation issues

Comment: And you can also use bean validation (`javax.validation`)

Comment: thanks for the answer. but you think that I am complicating a simple task. in real life, me have to do this. I have a SOAP service in which I get for example a user. I use cxf and it vaidate all. I map JAXBUser to domain user and save to DB. But also I have update method in my SOAP servce. And in this methiod I receive delta(only fields witch need update). And this fields always String-String. Where first string - field number(not name, just number) and second field - vaue. And it not has vaidation. I create factory of strategies and get needs strategy, by fiedNumber and validate and update it

Comment: What happens if I will use your example? For example, I receive data: 42:666. It means that I need get field number 42 and set value 666 to it. How can I do it in your case? I have factory of strategies. `Factory.getStrategyByFieldName(42);` I have one strategy for each field, and this strategy related with field number. And in each strategy I have logic. I can receive request for update 1 field or 20 fields.

Comment: @ip696, what I showed is not an example, it is pseudocode. It is not meant to be used as-is.

Comment: @qujck, in most domain models, we do not need to capture a one-to-one error message to each validation failure.

Assuming one has a workable error handler that preserves a stack trace, then a log shows that a generic "empty value" exception traces back to the setter of a particular field.

The one place where one needs fine-grained one-to-one mapping of error and field validation is at the UI level, where the UI must report what's wrong with a field and why. But that'd be at the input entry point, not at the object level... me thinks.

Comment: 1 / @ip696, I still don't see the need for this strategy approach, having worked myself with SOAP (using cfx, jbix, axis, etc.) You get the XML payload that gets de-serialized into a domain object that has validation built-in. Validation happens there.

Or the XML payload gets deserialized into a POJO without validation. That eventually must make its way through an object with validation, or into a database row (that should have its own constrains).

Either way, domain specific validation doesn't get refactored out except for very simple, baseline cases.

Comment: 2/ @ip696, that your domain model receives "delta" updates still doesn't lend itself to use this approach (where polymorphic setters to handle string/number deltas still rely on validation built into the object itself.) Maybe you do have a reason to pursue this, but I've worked in this domain for almost 30 years, I cannot visualize the problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: @qujck, I modified/extended my pseudocode and answer to address your observation.

Comment: @luis.espinal I asked another question and get the answer with advice use strategy. Just like I'm already doing. If you read this question, you better understand my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595354/correct-approachdesign-pattern-for-update-fields-in-java-object

Comment: The information expert principle (from GRASP) states that class having the information should carry out the responsability. So validating of model data is model responsability according this principle. What I dont like is the exception mechanism, I think exceptions are for things outside our software limits (database, connection errors), I would just use isValidName method in model or just use design by contract and just use asserts and treat a client trying to set a invalid name in model as a programming error (and fix client), the problem with the latter is write logic to validate views.