# Correct approach(design pattern) for update fields in java object

Tags: java, design-patterns, clean-architecture

I have java class **`Person`**:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String marriedStatus;
    private Date dob;
    //getters and setters
}
```

When I get new values for some fields of this object I can update it. But new fields values income in this format: `Map<String, String> newValues` where key - field number and value - the value of the field. I create this service:

```
public class UpdateService {
    public Person updateFields(Person targetPerson, Map<String, String> newValues){
        return null;
    }
}
```

I create a unit test and ask you to help implement this.

```
public class UpdateServiceTest {

    /*associations between field number and field name
    12 - name (length min: 2, max: 20. First letter must uppercase )
    18 - marriedStatus (only married, divorced, single)
    21  - age (only between 18 and 120)
    14  - dob (some format)
     */

    private Date dob;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        dob = new GregorianCalendar(2000, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 20).getTime();
    }

    @Test
    public void returnPersonWithUpdatedFields() {
        UpdateService updateService = new UpdateService();

        Person targetPerson = new Person();
        targetPerson.setName("Name");
        targetPerson.setMarriedStatus("MarriedStatus");
        targetPerson.setAge(20);
        targetPerson.setDob(dob);

        Map<String, String> newValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
        newValues.put("12", "Bill");
        newValues.put("18", "married ");
        newValues.put("21", "25");

        Person person = updateService.updateFields(targetPerson, newValues);

        assertEquals("Bill", person.getName());
        assertEquals("married", person.getMarriedStatus());
        assertEquals(25, person.getAge());
        assertEquals(dob, person.getDob());
    }
}
```

I need to get the person and update only fields which income in `Map<String, String> newValues`. And validate it.

Comment: I would say the approach of using a `Map<String, String> newValues` is fundamentally flawed. Why are there magic numbers that reference fields? I would suggest to fix the API / caller of the code.

Comment: In the comment inside the unit test some constraints are mentioned. This implies that you need to do validation as well, and thus you need to handle validation errors.

Comment: @ luk2302 oooo)))) that's a great point! But I can't fix API and I have to live with it. so I ask the question

Comment: @luk2302 'fundamentally flawed' applications are part of a developer's reality and don't always get priority to update.

Comment: @ Adriaan Koster yes, if field invalid I need to throw `new FieldValidationException(fieldNum)`

Comment: Iterate over the map, for each entry `switch` on the key and have a case for every magic number / field. That case then parses the data, validates it and then potentially assign it to a field. I doubt there is a nice pattern for it since (as I already said) it is a very bad design in the first place. Sure you can throw annotation processing on it and complex auto-magic stuff but that will hide what is actually happening. It is an ugly API, it will have an ugly implementation (imho).

Comment: Additionally, if you know the field names in the map won't change, you can create an `enum` and keep the field name values there so that their usage is simplified and you might avoid some misspellings / case problems.

Comment: @ luk2302 I create Enum with magic numbers like NAME("12"). And I create a strategy for each field. I iterate map and get strategy for each magic number(enum) and call `strategy.update(newValue)`. Is it a good approach in this case?

Comment: `It is an ugly API, it will have an ugly implementation (imho).` I totally agree with you. and wanted to quit when they gave me this API)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion how you could do this.

Model each field as a separate class, implementing a common `Field` interface.

Inject all known fields via the constructor and when a map is received, for each entry look up the matching field class to handle validation and updating.

With this approach you can test each field's validation and updating logic separately. Adding person fields will not make your service class grow. Testing the PersonUpdateService will only need to use one or two mocked Fields to validate the lookup and execution logic. A nice separation of concerns I'd say.

```
import java.util.*;

@Component
public class PersonUpdateService {

    private final List<Field> fields;

    @Autowired
    public PersonUpdateService(final List<Field> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    public void updatePerson(final Person person, final Map<String, String> update) {
        final boolean updated = false;
        update.forEach((key, value) -> this.findField(key).update(person, value));
    }

    private Field findField(final String index) {
        return this.fields.stream().filter(f -> f.index().equals(index)).findAny().orElseThrow(
                () -> new IllegalArgumentException("Field not found: " + index));
    }

}
```

The field interface:

```
public interface Field {
    String index();

    void update(Person person, String newValue);
}
```

An example field implementation:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Component
public class NameField implements Field {

    private static final String INDEX = "12";
    private static final String REGEX = "/^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]{1,19}$/";
    private static final String CONSTRAINTS = "length min: 2, max: 20. First letter must uppercase";

    @Override
    public String index() {
        return INDEX;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(final Person person, final String newValue) {
        if (!Pattern.matches(REGEX, newValue)) {
            throw new ValidationException(CONSTRAINTS);
        }
        person.setName(newValue);
    }

}
```

EDIT: added @Component and @Autowired annotations to indicate how dependency injection could be used in Spring. The available components implementing the Field interface will automatically be collected by Spring and injected via the constructor. In your unit test for the service you can inject one or two mock Fields. Don't test the actual validation/updating logic of the field implementations in the service test, but create separate unit tests for each field class.

EDIT 2: the above advice about writing unit tests is from my (mockist) perspective. Classical unit testers would probably write a single test to cover the complete specs (like the test you provided in the post). The reason I don't prefer that is that edge cases get lost easier in such an integration-style unit test and the chance increases that you are making false assumptions about how the code works or that you have to repeatedly exercise the same code in your tests. However this is a long-standing debate and there are multiple points of view which all have their merits.

Comment: It is exactly like I did))) Thank you! But what about validation? how do you think - Is it correct to implement it in this class? `NameField `. I did so in the first version of my implementation. But now I create separately class `FieldValidator` and move validation logit to this class. is it correct?

Comment: I create a custom annotation `@UpdateFieldType(type = NAME)` inherite `@Component`)))

Comment: I think one class per field is enough so far. The NameField class is already pretty small. Even though it does two things (validating the newValue and updating the Person instance) I would not split it up unless further complexity/requirements arise.

Comment: I don't know what you need the annotation for but it smells like over-engineering to me. Keep it simple!